# How do i record stopwatch times in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, stopwatch

I would like to know how i can get the ending stopwatch time string once i have stopped the timer. I'm using this [repo](https://github.com/bizz84/stopwatch-flutter) to make my stopwatch. Once i have stopped the timer i want the timer that is displayed to be put in a list so that i can record my times on a page like this:[Times page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HopWm.png). Would it use the If/else function?
Thanks Hunter

Comment: Could you provide the code you have so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AndreyOzornin yeah sure: gist.github.com/HunterColly/01febf74cd116698dff1db7c2049a858